# EPPlus - Pivot Table how to show values as % of Grand Total

Tags: c#, pivot-table, epplus

When creating a Pivot table using EPPlus library, we can add the row fields using `PivotTable.RowFields.Add(...)` function, similarly the data fields can be added using the `PivotTable.DataFields.Add(...)` function.

The issue is when I want to show the values of data field as percentage (%) of the grand total (see below image, setting used in actual Excel pivot table). The data field only gives `DataFieldFunctions.Sum`, `Count`, `Average` etc. But, there is no setting which allows the field value to be show as % of the grand total.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPPlus doesn't support "Show Value As" feature for pivot data fields, but [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194712/Advanced-Excels-With-EPPlus#bm1141) describes a nice trick modifying the XML data behind the pivot table.

The main idea behind this, is that you set your data field's function to sum, and it's display format to percentage with EPPlus, and the rest with OpenXML.

If `pivotTable` is your Pivot and `dataField` is the Data Field you are working with than the code example on the mentioned page gives the following solution:

```
var xdoc = pivotTable.PivotTableXml;
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);

var schemaMain = xdoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
if (nsm.HasNamespace("x") == false)
    nsm.AddNamespace("x", schemaMain);

var dataFieldNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(
    "/x:pivotTableDefinition/x:dataFields/x:dataField[@name='" + dataField.Name + "']",
    nsm
);

dataFieldNode.AppendAttribute("showDataAs", "percentOfTotal");
```

Comment: Works!! Thank you for taking time to post it.